# Running from shortcut does not perform the same as running through Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, windows-10

I created a VS vb.net program that uses the windows media player. The program works great. However when I create a desktop shortcut to the Release/bin folder, some or the videos have issues (don't start right away, blurred for a few seconds, etc). If I go to the folder and run the .exe, it works. If I make a dos.bat file (cd & exec), it works. If I run the shortcut as administrator, it works.
I rather no run as admin, especially not knowing why. I'm not sure why a shortcut is different than a manual run or running from a dos prompt.

**Update:** It appears that it has nothing to do with the shortcut! I have the shortcut on screen #2, so that is where the program starts. If I drag the window to screen #1 or start it there, Then the program works OK!
When I ran as administrator or dos batch, the program starts on screen #1 regardless of where the shortcut is.

So it appears that the real problem is: It will only run properly on screen #1. Other screens have the display issues. I have (4) screens. 1 & 2 are one model and 3 & 4 are another and smaller.

Answer (score 0):

i think it depends on where your shortcut is located.

for instance, some people make their profile on a network share (effectively your desktop is a network location), so a shortcut on desktop is actually a link to on a network location which normally has permission restrictions.

another case is that the shortcut you created might not have the "Start in" set to the desired place (your bin/debug folder).

so i think it's worth to examine both of above...

Comment: I do place the shortcut on the desktop and I do have the "Start in" set. If I place the shortcut in the bin/debug folder, the program works correctly. I did not know about the desktop, but that is where I want it. My desktop is not shared.  I'm not sure what to do next.